# Is there any query to get the selected column headers in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table name `test_comments` with 4 fields:

```
id
comments
guests
user
```

I want to fetch only the column heading comments and guests of this table

I had used `show columns from <tablename>` but it fetched all the column headings

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Make an array of all the columns you need and check against those returned from the SQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: you need to only column name or other information also if other information also then what other information...if you share then I can help you even you can fetch own from information_schema.

Comment: i need only the column name but only selected one and not any of the other information

Answer (score 2):

You can use a solution like this:

```
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'test_comments' AND ORDINAL_POSITION IN(2,3);
```

The ordinal position of the column in the table. The first column in the table is number 1.
you need to fetch only the column heading comments and guests of this table so use ORDINAL_POSITION IN(2,3)

Comment: You should explain why you add `AND ORDINAL_POSITION IN(2,3)`

Comment: He need  only the column heading comments and guests of this table so use ORDINAL_POSITION IN(2,3)